# Managing dynamic Add and remove element with nicEdit plugin

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Hi sorry for this silly question,

basically I have dynamic add element with `textarea` incorporated with nicEdit plugins

if I tap `"Add Another InputBox"` 3 element added up but my problem is the `"remove"` link inline with newly created elements, I can't figure out how to make it works.

my jsfiddle is here : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kodewrecker/vZZ8F/3/)

any comments or suggestion is well appreciated. THanks!

**ANSWER**

Here is exactly what I need to be as answer to this Question. 
By the help of .clone of Jquery. It works perfect.

here's the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vh3Js/1/).

Comment: You should implement a div the wraps the whole section and then have remove link remove the whole div. This way you will not have elements left behind.

Comment: its the remove button after add doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Check here DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/vZZ8F/4/

I added `<div class="newBox">` when you create new, so that it is easier to find and remove.

```
$(document).on('click', '.remScnt', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var elem = $(this).prev('textarea');
     var index = this.rel; 
     editors[index].removeInstance(elem[0]);
     delete editors[index];
     $(this).parent().siblings('div.newBox').remove();
     $(this).parent().remove();
 });
```

Comment: it works in one click of add element,but try multiple click of add element then remove...but thanks thanks!

Comment: I will check and update again :)

Comment: your so kind. Thanks I myself altering your code too.. THanks